# Database table lock is not released after rollback?

Tags: java, javafx, oracle11g

I'm using Oracle XE DB. I have a screen to save an invoice. When saving the invoice, the items should be deducted from the inventory. But if one of the items has no stock, an error will be raised. If this happens, the entire Invoice should be deleted.

Here comes my problem ... when I issue:

```
SalesInvoiceDAO.deleteSalesInvoice(InvoiceId);
```

The Application hangs so in the method i queried the table for the Invoice i want to delete before deleting to see what is happening it raises nullpointexception meaning that this invoice doesn't exist while it does exist: I can see it in DB.  I'm guessing there is a lock on this table but why? I rolled back before trying to delete it. Shouldn't the rollback remove all locks??

This is the code:

```
    @FXML
private void saveInvoiceAction(ActionEvent event) {
    int invId = 0;
    if (tableList.size() > 0) {
        SalesInvoice invoice = new SalesInvoice();
        invoice.setUserId(SessionBean.getUserId());
        invoice.setShiftId(SessionBean.getShiftId());
        invoice.setBranchId(SessionBean.getUserBranch());
        invoice.setCustomerId(3578);
        invoice.setTotal(Double.parseDouble(totalTextItem.getText()));
        try {
            invId = SalesInvoiceDAO.insertSalesInvoice(invoice);
            Database.getInstance().commit();
            System.out.println("SalesInvoice Id is: " + invId);
            for (int i = 0; i < tableList.size(); i++) {
                Item item = tableList.get(i);
                SalesInvoiceItem siItem = new SalesInvoiceItem();
                siItem.setSalesInvoiceId(invId);
                siItem.setProdId(item.getProductId());
                siItem.setProdMesure(item.getProdMesureId());
                siItem.setProdUnit(item.getUnitId());
                siItem.setUnitFactor(item.getUnitFactor());
                siItem.setBasePrice(item.getBasePrice());
                siItem.setQnty(item.getQntySold());

                SalesInvoiceItemDAO.insertSalesInvoiceItem(siItem);
                //Print 2 Reciepts
            }
            Database.getInstance().commit();
            showAlert("info", "Success", "Saved Successfully!", null);
            tableList.clear();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            try {
                Database.getInstance().rollback();
                SalesInvoiceDAO.deleteSalesInvoice(invId);
                System.out.println("Saving Invoice Faild\n Error: " + ex.getMessage());
                showAlert("error", "Error!", "Something Went Wrong!", ex.getMessage());
            } catch (SQLException ex1) {
                System.out.println("Deleting Invoice Failed!!\n" + ex1.getMessage());
                showAlert("error", "Error!", "Deleting Invoice Failed", ex1.getMessage());
                Logger.getLogger(MainPageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
            }
        }
    } else {
        showAlert("warning", "Warrning!", "Nothing To Save!", null);
    }
```

## Update 1

```
   public static void deleteSalesInvoice(int invoiceId) throws SQLException{        
    try {
        SalesInvoice invoice = getSalesInvoiceByInvId(invoiceId);
        System.out.println("Invoice "+invoice.getInvoiceId()+" Exists!");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {            
        System.out.println("");
        Logger.getLogger(SalesInvoiceDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }         
    String sql = "DELETE FROM SALES_INVOICE WHERE SALES_INVOICE_ID = ?";
    PreparedStatement stmnt = Database.setconnection().prepareStatement(sql);
    stmnt.setInt(1, invoiceId);
    Database.getInstance().execUpdate(stmnt);
}
```

## Update 2

```
    public class Database {
        //"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
        private static final String username = "HAZARDV3";
        private static final String password = "H";
        private static final String thinConn = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
        private static Database database;
        private static Connection conn;  

        private Database(){        
                System.out.println("Databse loading ..");
                new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            if(conn==null){
                            setconnection();
                            }
                        } catch (SQLException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }                
                }).start();              
        }    
        /* We create this static method so that all view share the same Database instance
        *  While the constructor is private 
        *  Now instead of calling "new Database();" from controllers we'll call "Database.getInstance();"
        */
        public static Database getInstance(){
            if(database == null){
                database = new Database();
            }
            return database;
        }

        public static Connection setconnection() throws SQLException {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(thinConn, username, password);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            return conn;
        }
        public void rollback() throws SQLException{
            conn.rollback();
        }
}
```

## Update 3

To isolate the possibility that the problem might be related to the database implementation, I created a PL/SQL program to mimic the saving method in the application, The third insert statement should raise an exception:

```
BEGIN

INSERT INTO SALES_INVOICE(SALES_INVOICE_ID, SHIFT_ID, BRANCH_ID, TOTAL, DISCOUNT, PAYED, CUSTOMER_ID, USER_ID)
VALUES(466, 110,    2087,       156.299,    0,  0,  3578, 1);

COMMIT;

INSERT INTO SALES_INVOICE_ITEMS(SALES_INVOICE_ID, PROD_ID, PROD_UNIT, PROD_PRICE, QNTY, REFUND, PROD_MESURE, UNIT_FACTOR, BASE_PRICE, RETURNED)
VALUES(466, 1,  2727,   0,  2,  0,      2726, 1, 0.299,  0);


INSERT INTO SALES_INVOICE_ITEMS(SALES_INVOICE_ID, PROD_ID, PROD_UNIT, PROD_PRICE, QNTY, REFUND, PROD_MESURE, UNIT_FACTOR, BASE_PRICE, RETURNED)
VALUES(466, 2,  2727,   0,  2,  0,      2726, 1, 0.299,  0);

COMMIT;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
ROLLBACK;
DELETE FROM SALES_INVOICE WHERE SALES_INVOICE_ID = 466;

END;
```

The result is exactly what i want, it rollback and deletes the invoice.
So i can safely say now that the problem is either in my java code or maybe a bug in JavaFX.

Comment: @Glenn I do intend to commit, because in the DB trigger that deducts from inventory i need to query based on some information in the invoice, and for some reason i must commit the invoice otherwise it hangs.

Comment: Are you getting an actual Oracle error? Attempting to delete a row that doesn't exist won't throw an Oracle exception.

Comment: @TurtlesAllTheWayDown no it's not an Oracle error ... it's a nullpointerexception becasue in the deleteSalesInvoice(invId) i check for the existence of the invoice first ... but even if i remove the checking the Invoice don't get deleted.

Comment: @TurtlesAllTheWayDown I updated the question for clarification.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. You mention deleteSalesInvoice(), but do not show the code or stack trace.

Comment: @TurtlesAllTheWayDown actually when removing the checking the application hangs ... sorry but i've been trying to fix this for days i lost track.

Comment: This look suspicious: Database.getInstance(); please post the code for this method.

Comment: 2@MartínStraus Please refer to Update 2.